# Redefinitions of constexpr static data members are allowed now? (but not inline const)?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

The following fails to compile under both gcc and clang in c++14, but succeeds with c++1z:

```
struct Cls {
  static constexpr int N = 0;
};
constexpr int Cls::N;
constexpr int Cls::N;
```

The C++14 error is predictable: `redefinition of ‘constexpr const int Cls::N’`

What changed to make this legal? I found:

> *n4659 10.1.5 [dcl.constexpr]*
>
> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr
>   specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable

So I thought it might have to do with inline variables, but the following fails for c++1z under both compilers

```
struct Cls {
  static inline const int N = 0;
};
inline const int Cls::N; // note, only one definition here
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before C++17, you needed to re-declare all `static` variables outside the class in exactly one translation unit (typically each translation unit is a `.cpp` file and vice versa, but this isn’t required). As you pointed out, C++17 introduces `inline` class member variables, and `static constexpr` variables automatically qualify. You are *not* allowed to redeclare `inline` variables outside the class, as you saw in your second example, but an exception was made for `constexpr` because previously you were allowed (and in fact required) to do so, but the syntax is deprecated.

In [class.static.data]p2, it allows that syntax for non-inline members (“The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of
an incomplete type other than cv void. The definition for a static data member that is not defined inline
in the class definition shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.”)

In the next paragraph, the standard allows `constexpr` outside-of-class declarations and requires them for non-`constexpr` data (emphasis added):

> If a non-volatile non-inline `const` static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration
>   in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in
>   which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a
>   constant expression (8.20). The member shall still be defined in a
>   namespace scope if it is odr-used (6.2) in the program and the
>   namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*. An inline
>   static data member may be defined in the class definition
>   and may specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. **If the member is
>   declared with the `constexpr` specifier, it may be redeclared in
>   namespace scope with no initializer** (this usage is deprecated; see
>   D.1). Declarations of other static data members shall not specify a
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

And here’s the deprecation note, D.1 Redeclaration of static constexpr data members [depr.static_constexpr]:

> For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the
>   class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   static constexpr int n = 5; // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
> };
> constexpr int A::n; // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]