# Does redeclaring a static const member as constexpr automatically qualify it to be inline?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Consider this use case of a `static constexpr` member:

```
// smart_enum.h
class smart_enum {
    // Some data, operations, etc.
    // Cannot use constexpr here, smart_enum is incomplete at this point
    static const smart_enum first, second;
};

constexpr smart_enum smart_enum::first = {}, smart_enum::second = {};
```

Are `first` and `second` automatically `inline` variables? Or do I need to qualify them as such? Or am I unable to qualify them as inline and need to provide a definition in some source file later? I have always been confused by this "redefinition" from `const` to `constexpr` and would like more light to be shed on what this really means.

Specifically I am wondering about the interaction of `const` declaration to `constexpr` definition and how that plays out with automatic `inline` of a `static constexpr` ([Redefinitions of constexpr static data members are allowed now? (but not inline const)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019980))

Comment: "Also, the ​constexpr​ specifier implies  inline for static data members as well as functions." - however I'd put that constexpr in the class I think.

Comment: @lorro but you can't put it in the class, which is where my confusion stems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the standard says:

> [c++17-12.2.3.2-2]The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv void.

now, maybe your confusion stems from believing that the two expressions

```
static const smart_enum first; // class scope
constexpr smart_enum smart_enum::first = ...; // namespace scope
```

declare different types. This is not the case because the type of a `constexpr T` is still `const T` ( in fact you can always write `constexpr const T` to mean the same thing ).

So, in your code, you first declare a name 'first' of incomplete type 'const smart_enum', then you leter define it as "constexpr smart_enum" ( or "constexpr **inline const** smart_enum" if we add everything constexpr implies explictly ).

Answer (score 1):

In C++14, no variables are inline, of course.  Making variables like this automatically inline was an unintentional **breaking** change (since it means that the definition *must* appear in every translation unit).  I filed [CWG2531](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2531.html) to try to have this rectified.  There are now of course backwards-compatibility concerns with C++17 implementations, although any code that wants the other behavior can just add `inline` to the out-of-class definition as is already allowed.